# Get associative table data from 2 level depths relationship in django using foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models

This is my problem that im trying to figure out being a beginner with django

1. I want to get the country in `user` app knowing that city table is connected to country table using foreign key. User table has city_id column. Please note that user already logged in. I get the city already but not the country
2. After that in my `instructor` app, i get that currency which is connected to country column currency_id.

This is what i have.

/instructors/model.py

```
from django.db import models
from locations.models import City, Country

class Class(models.Model):
   ...
   city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank=True)


class Currency(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=7, help_text="Code HTML")
    initials = models.CharField(max_length=5, help_text="e.g. : CLP (Chilean Pesos)")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "currencies"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_label(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.symbol, self.initials)
```

/users/model.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    ...

    def get_locality(self):
        locality = ''
        if self.location:
            locality = '%s, %s, %s' % (self.location.name, self.location.city.name, self.city.country.name)
        elif self.city:
            locality = '%s, %s' % (self.city.name, self.city.country.name)
        return locality
```

/locations/model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    currency_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "countries"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "cities"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.name, self.country)


class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "locations"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.name, self.city)
```

Comment: I see that you're already referencing related objects in your `get_locality` method. What are you trying to do that you don't know how to do? Getting the `Currency` for the user should look something like `self.city.country.currency`, depending on what you named your `ForeignKey` field on the `Country` model.

Comment: actually the self.location.city.country.name doesn't return the expected data

Comment: If you add in your location models I'll see if there's anything obviously wrong. Is `self.location` another FK field on your `User` model?

Comment: yes you are correct it is another FK

Comment: Your location models all look fine - `self.location.city.country.name` should work. What does it return? Have you tried walking through the FK chain? EG, see what `self.location` is, then `self.location.city`, etc. For your country/currency connection, you'd do better with an FK from `Country` to `Currency` rather than trying to implement it with an integer ID field.

Comment: i will modify the fk for country.  Thanks Peter, like you said i tried it and figure out the problem my current user doesn't have a city id. That's why. Been stumbling in this for hours already. :)